# How to move selected UV Island?

Tags: python, uv

I want to move the island in UV Editor, but it moves the faces in the 3D View

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.0192062, 0.49296, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```

in Blender 2.71 with python

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the context's area type first, run the folowing script from the text editor not from the console:

```
import bpy
area = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.209548, 0.232831, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.context.area.type = area
```

Related

- [Python - move UV for selected items](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/python-move-uv-for-selected-items)