# Problem moving selected UV islands with Python

Tags: python, uv

I've read all questions and answers about moving UV island here. The most relevant are these:

- [How to move selected UV Island?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/how-to-move-selected-uv-island?lq=1)
- [Python - move UV for selected items](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/python-move-uv-for-selected-items)

But they do not solve my problem, my code is just not working. What is wrong with my code?

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(125, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
    else:
        area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

This is the result:

[image]

The other areas changed to VIEW_3D, but the IMAGE_EDITOR area did not make the translate. The translate is still happening to the object in VIEW_3D.

Comment: I think it as to do with the position of the mouse, try running the script with it on top of the UV Image editor

Comment: I'm not programming at Blender's Text Editor - I'm programming python with gedit. When I run the script, it creates a new Blender file with my commands. Because of this, doesn't matter my mouse position - also because I can't control this. Maybe what could be done is to leave all areas and keep open just "Image Editor" area. Do you know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change my code, and use one "meta-code" - inside my code, I've opened an "Text Editor" area, and include another python file. At least, this is my code:

```
text = bpy.data.texts.load("translate.py")

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
        area.spaces[0].text = text

        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['edit_text'] = text
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]

        bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
        break

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'TEXT_EDITOR':
        area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

And, my translate.py code:

```
import bpy

area = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.449219, 0.425781, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.context.area.type = area
```

Thanks everybody :)