# Move selected face UVs specific amount while in 3d viewport

Tags: python, 3d-view, transforms, uv-image-editor

What I’d like to do is have a face selection in the 3d viewport (sometimes on multiple objects), click a hotkey and the selected face UVs get moved up one UV tile. I’m still relatively new to working with python and don’t know where to start.

I’ve found [this older](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/python-move-uv-for-selected-items) answer but its pre blender 2.8 and doesn’t work for me.
Is there anyone who can help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are after a script answer consider adding the python tag to question.

Comment: Are you looking for a specifically Python solution?  The way to do it without Python is g y 1 enter in UV editor.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, I'm looking for a python solution to this since I'd ideally want to avoid having to move the UVs manually in the UV editor

Comment: Updating scripts is a good way to start learning bpy, re older answer `context.scene.objects.active` as been replaced by `context.view_layer.objects.active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I got it working off of the older answer I linked to.
It moves the selected faces up one UV tile in the active UV channel. Works with multiple objects selected

```
# Credit to iKlsR https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/python-move-uv-for-selected-items
    
import bpy

# grab the current area
original_area = bpy.context.area.type
view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
    
# switch to the UV editor to perform transforms etc
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'UV'
    
# make sure select sync is on
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_uv_select_sync = True
    
# move the selection
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False))
    
# return to the original mode where the script was run
bpy.context.area.type = original_area
```